# Creating graph from pairs of vertices while having minimum distance between them

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I will write my problem like this:

- I have an undirected graph with "empty" vertices, but with weighted edges (let's call it distance)
- Also, I have pairs of directed "fillings" for vertices, so for example, pair 1->2, means from vertex containing one to vertex containing 2. 20->13 means pair of 2 vertices, one filled with number 20, another one with 13.. and so on
- I can place the "fillings" of vertices anywhere I want in the graph, not depending on a pair - every number from pair will symbolize only 1 vertex
- Each vertex has the maximum of 2 outcoming/incoming edges, but there might be a pair with only one (so, basically, single)
- There will be cycles

And I want to generate a graph with the shortest distance between the given pair of vertices.

> ```
>  One short and simple example
> ```
>
> graph
>
> ```
>              X---X---X
>              |       |
>              X----X--+
> ```
>
> with pairs of
>                1->2
>                1->3
>                3->4
>                2->5
>                4->5
>
> ```
> will produce something like
>
> 1---2---5
> |       |
> 3----4--+
> ```

I know this can be done by brute-force and F-Warshal algorithm. The question is, if there is not a better approach (for 50 vertices, there is 50! combinations - a lot for calculation)

Once again, thanks for your time and if, even more for answers :)
Have a great day

Comment: A few things aren't clear.  "I want to generate a graph with the shortest distance between the given pair of vertices" -- this refers to a *single* pair, but it sounds like you are given a *set* of pairs.  If you meant "set", then for the 2 pairs 1->2 and 3->4, how to decide whether an assignment of labels to vertices (BTW that's how I would phrase that) that puts 1 and 2 very close together but 3 and 4 very far apart is "better" than an assignment that puts each pair fairly close together?

Comment: Thanks for better phrasing  - I will edit it in a while. And to your question, if there is an assignment which puts each pair close together, prefer and use that one. Generally speaking, let each pair have the shortest distance between them possible.

Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm afraid that the problem with the description you just gave of what makes an assignment "good" is that it doesn't give a way to decide, *for any given pair of solutions*, which one is better (or whether they are equally good).  For a computer program to be able to find the "best" something, it has to be able to compare two somethings.  The usual way to do this is to describe a way to compute a score for any given solution, and then ask for a solution that maximises (or minimises) this score.  Can you think of a good scoring function?

Comment: If you want to minimize the sum of edge lengths, you cannot do anything. The sum of edge lengths is dictated by the initial graph template. No matter how you assign the vertices, it will always have the same summed edge length. And if you have only degree-2 vertices and (at most?) one degree-1 vertex, the only thing you can do is cycle the sequence through the graph. So, there are not really many options you have.